# Unable to connect to MKS: Could not locate vmware-authd executable

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vcenter

i am glad to be part of this community , wanted to stop by , say hello and share my sadness.
i have installed a vcenter applience 6.0 with a hope to manage some of my old 5.0 esxi servers , everything went smoth ,but the main feature that i was looking for the standalone VMRC gave up on me.

Unable to connect to the MKS: Could not connect to pipe \.\pipe\vmware-authdpipe within retry period

> from Windows Server 2012  Standard

Unable to connect to MKS: Could not locate vmware-authd executable

> from MacOS Sierra  10.12.5

some details
vMware Remote console 10.0.1 build-5898794 (Windows )
vMware Remote console 10.0.1 (5898794) ( Mac OS)
vMware ESXi 5.0 Update 1
vMware vCenter 6.0.0.30200

i have tried google this topic:

1) telnet server (esxi host ) 902 - works good
2) the DNS resolves
3) tried to reconnect the esxi in the maintenance mode 
https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2115126

feeling depressed , need an advice

thx in advace for any help

Answer (score 4):

VMRC 10 defaults to only using TLS 1.2 and I know ESXi 4.1 does not like that (ESXi 5.5 is OK with it, but I'm not sure about ESXi 5.0).  (VMRC 9 doesn't have this issue because it allows the older versions of SSL/TLS.)

Add the following line to "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Remote Console\config.ini" as an administrator to allow VMRC 10 to connect to older ESXi:

```
tls.protocols=tls1.0,tls1.1,tls1.2
```

Comment: The above posted by kjpires is the resolution for the fix - the path on a *nix system would be /etc/vmware/config,
and the part to paste in there is <code>tls.protocols="tls1.0,tls1.1,tls1.2"</code>